# how to save game state/preferences in android using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to save the values of various variables which my game is progressing, like logo number or lives available, etc using **LIBGDX** framework.

Code goes as such:

```
static Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My_state");
public static void ContinuePutstate() {
    prefs.putInteger("option", MenuScreen.option);
    prefs.putInteger("lifes", Loadassets.lifes);
    prefs.putInteger("hammertouch", Loadassets.hammertouch);
    prefs.putInteger("multilogonum", Loadmultiple.multilogonum);
    prefs.putInteger("brushtouch", Loadassets.brushtouch);
    prefs.putInteger("leveluser", Loadassets.Leveluser);
    prefs.putInteger("iconnumber", CorrectScreen.iconnumber);

    System.out.println("HAd saved option "+prefs.getInteger("option")+" and original option is "+MenuScreen.option);
}
```

When I tried to print that, I am getting option 0 but `menuscreen` option actually has another value.

Comment: Be careful with activity state stored in static variables.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411126/android-libgdx-prefs-getting-lost/18413472#18413472

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after putting all values use

```
prefs.flush();
```

this will write the data to preferences

see
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Preferences#Flushing

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that creating a singular static instance is the proper way to go with the LibGDX Preferences framework, because the Android OS allows you to obtain only one preferences instance, and not more. Meaning, if you tried to get more preferences than just a single one, the key-value pairs would not be saved.